# Short Way to Loop through a Series of List, Do Some Actions and Assign it Back to the List

Tags: python

For example I have three lists namely; listA, listB, and listC. I want to pass each list in a function(*for ex. dedup*) and then assign it back to that respective list.

```
listA = dedup(listA)
listB = dedup(listB)
listC = dedup(listC)
```

I imagine doing something like this...

```
listA, listB, listC = (dedup(list) for list in range(3))
```

Unfortunately, this is not working.

Comment: `listA, listB, listC = [dedup(list) for list in (listA, listB, listC)]` probably?

Comment: If you want to pass some number of objects through a function inline - anyway you should save them in some container. Also you may play with globals\locals but...

Comment: listA, listB, listC = [dedup(list) for list in (listA, listB, listC)] is not working as well

Comment: I don't think so. It is working. But you should use `map` as Farhood ET said.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it's working!

Comment: @olbinado11 Or you could also handle them within the function, posted an edit for that approach! cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps, combining the lists and a comprehension upon:

```
def dedup(lst):
    return lst[::-1]   # just to return a reversed lst

listA = [1,2,3]
listB = [4,5,6]
listC = [7,8,9]

cList = [listA,listB,listC]    
listA, listB, listC = [dedup(lst) for lst in cList]
print(listA)
print(listB)
print(listC)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[3, 2, 1]
[6, 5, 4]
[9, 8, 7]
```

**EDIT**:

Another way could be to just pass all the lists to the function and handle those inside:

```
def dedup2(cList):
    temp = []
    for e in cList:
        temp.append(e[::-1])
    return temp

listA, listB, listC = dedup2(cList)
print(listA)
print(listB)
print(listC)
```

**Shorter-version** (using list comprehension):

```
def dedup2(cList):
    return [t[::-1] for t in cList]

listA, listB, listC = dedup2(cList)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Using map():

```
listA, listB, listC = map(dedup, [listA, listB, listC])
```

Comment: Please add `map` usage to your answer.

Comment: @sashaaero added. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
listA, listB, listC = map(dedup, [listA, listB, listC])
```

Or

```
listA, listB, listC = [dedup(x) for x in [listA, listB, listC]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
def square(f):
    return [i*i for i in f]

l1 = [1,2,4]
l2 = [7,8,9]
l3 = [12,13,14]

l = [l1,l2,l3]


l1, l2, l3 = [square(lst) for lst in l]
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

The left side of the `=` doesn't know what's on the right side, so using `range` like that won't work. You need to specify the `lists` you want to operate on:

```
listA, listB, listC = (dedup(l) for l in [listA, listB, listC])
```

Also, it's generally unwise to use `list` as a variable, even a temporary one. Doing so shadows the builtin `list` class.

The real question, though, is where did those `lists` come from? Presumably, if they were linked in some way, they should have been collected into some container, which could then be passed to the above comprehension.